# Converting lines of text from a text file to multiple columns in Java

Tags: java

I want to convert the following input from a text file to column format.

Input text:

I am going to Chicago.

X1: going

X2: I am

X3: to Chicago

He is playing football.

X1: is playing

X2: He

X3: football

Expected output:

I               X2

am              X2

going           X1

to              X3

Chicago         X3

He              X2

is              X1

playing         X1

football        X3

---

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/input.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
   InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8"));
   while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
     {

          if(!(line.startsWith("X1:")

             {
                        String words[]=line.split(" ");
                        for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
                        {

                             //System.out.println(words[i]);
                             String abc[] = words[i].split(" ",100); 
                             String w="";
                             for(int j=0; j<abc.length;j++)
                             {
                              //System.out.println(abc[j]);
                                 if(j<99)
                                     //w=w+abc[j]+"\t"+"\n";
                                     w=w+abc[j]+"\t";
                                 else
                                     w=w+abc[j];
                        }

                             str.append("\n");
                             str.append(w);
                             str.append("\n");
                             System.out.println(w);
                             fw.write(w);
                             fw.write("\n");

                        }
                        str.append("\n");


                   }//end of if
              }
```

Comment: Could you post whatever you 've tried so far? Thanks

Comment: You need a loop. In each iteration you read one sentence and all the word groups for that sentence, process that and produce an output.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to parse the text file and look for keywords like "X1:", "X2", and "X3:" and store the string that comes after it.

When you have read the complete sentence, store it into a String and do something like the following:

```
String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");
```

which will split individual words by space. Do the same for Strings that come after the keywords "X1:", "X2:", and "X3:" from the text file.

Then, say you have each word in X1 stored as an array of String:

```
ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

for(String word : words) {
    for(int j = 0; j < X1.length; j++) {
        if(X1[j].equals(word))
            output.add(word + " X1");
    }

    // do the same for X2, X3
}

// Print out the output
for(String elem : output)
    System.out.println(elem);
```